# Launch file doesn't work after xacro update

Tags: roslaunch, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

After updating to version 1.9.4 of the ros-indigo-xacro package, one of my launch files doesn't work anymore, and I can't figure out why. The error mesages I get are the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 706, in main
    open_output(output_filename).write(doc.toprettyxml(indent='  '))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb7' in position 1960: ordinal not in range(128)
while processing /home/daniel/catkin_ws/src/rotors_simulator/rotors_gazebo/launch/spawn_mav.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [     /opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/daniel/catkin_ws/src/rotors_simulator/rotors_description/urdf/firefly_base.xacro'     enable_logging:=false     enable_ground_truth:=true     log_file:=firefly     mav_name:=firefly] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="     $(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(arg model)'     enable_logging:=$(arg enable_logging)     enable_ground_truth:=$(arg enable_ground_truth)     log_file:=$(arg log_file)     mav_name:=$(arg mav_name)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

The launch file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<launch>
  <arg name="mav_name" />
  <arg name="model" default="$(find rotors_description)/urdf/$(arg mav_name)_base.xacro"/>
  <arg name="tf_prefix" default="$(optenv ROS_NAMESPACE)"/>
  <arg name="x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="0.1"/>
  <arg name="enable_logging" default="false"/>
  <arg name="enable_ground_truth" default="true"/>
  <arg name="log_file" default="$(arg mav_name)"/>

  <!-- send the robot XML to param server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="
    $(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(arg model)'
    enable_logging:=$(arg enable_logging)
    enable_ground_truth:=$(arg enable_ground_truth)
    log_file:=$(arg log_file)
    mav_name:=$(arg mav_name)"
  />
  <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="$(arg tf_prefix)" />

  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_$(arg mav_name)" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
   args="-param robot_description
         -urdf
         -x $(arg x)
         -y $(arg y)
         -z $(arg z)
         -model $(arg mav_name)"
   respawn="false" output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207151/launch-file-doesn%27t-work-after-xacro-update/) by [DanielEckert](https://answers.ros.org/users/22166/danieleckert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Daniel, I don't know if you've already solved this issue, but this is being caused by some comments in the xacro files which have the middle dot. A solution has been posted in the github issues section of rotors_simulator.

https://github.com/PX4/rotors_simulator/issues/17

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-22**:
So it was middle dot after all.

**Comment by [DanielEckert](https://answers.ros.org/users/22166/danieleckert/) on 2015-04-22**:
Thanks, that could have been it. I just updated the repository I was working with a few days later, and reinstalled, and then things worked. Not sure what the actual issue was.

**Comment by [aamir](https://answers.ros.org/users/21054/aamir/) on 2015-06-02**:
I had exactly the same problem as asked by Daniel for exactly the same launch file (after xarco update). I went down upto firefly.urdf.xacro and removed all middle dots from kg.m and kg.m^2 by an asterisks and then it worked. Note that all those middle dots were inside commented parts of the xml.